# Camera never activates LowLightBoost

Tags: ios6, camera

I have the following code running on my iPhone V:

```
// Create the capture device
camera = [CameraManager cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
if (camera.lowLightBoostSupported) {
    if ([camera lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        camera.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES;
        [camera unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

But the lowLightBoost never activates, even if I put the device with the backside on the table so the preview image is pitch black.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"LowLight active: %@ Camera lowlightWhenAvailable: %@",camera.isLowLightBoostEnabled ? @"true": @"false",camera.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable ? @"true": @"false");
```

gives me

2013-10-25 10:21:53.179 aCoDriver[1019:668f] LowLight active: false Camera lowlightWhenAvailable: true
2013-10-25 10:21:53.429 aCoDriver[1019:668f] LowLight active: false Camera lowlightWhenAvailable: true
2013-10-25 10:21:53.679 aCoDriver[1019:668f] LowLight active: false Camera lowlightWhenAvailable: true
2013-10-25 10:21:53.929 aCoDriver[1019:668f] LowLight active: false Camera lowlightWhenAvailable: true

Comment: have you had solution to this?

Comment: no. I suspect it is the mode how I get the image from the camera. I get YUV format. I would check if this happens also if you get RGB. If you find out more please let me know.

Comment: have you tried creating observer like Jawboxer did? That could probably help you debug and find out if the lowLightBoost is ever activated at all

Comment: Yes I did. Was never called.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I'm not sure why that wouldn't work.  If it helps, here's what I do - along with registering for notifications so you can see exactly when the low light boost switches itself on/off (for example, if you're pointing the camera a bright light and then lay it down flat on a table, you should receive a notification indicating that the low light boost switched on). This works perfectly for me in iOS 6/7:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = _stillCamera.inputCamera;
NSError *error;

if(device.lowLightBoostSupported) {
    // NSLog(@"low light is supported");

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL boostEnabled = [prefs boolForKey:@"lowLightBoostEnabled"];

    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        device.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = boostEnabled;

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }

    // register as an observer of changes to lowLightBoostEnabled
    [device addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"lowLightBoostEnabled" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
}


// for observing changes to _stillCamera.inputCamera.lowLightBoostEnabled
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"lowLightBoostEnabled"]) {

        NSLog(@"lowLightBoostEnabled changed");

        NSNumber *boostIsActiveValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

        BOOL boostIsActive = boostIsActiveValue.boolValue;

        NSLog(@"is low light boost currently active: %d", boostIsActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately it does not work on my device. lowLightBoostSupported is true and it sets automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable to true. But after that lowLightBoostEnabled remains false even if I wrap the device in a blanket. I think I try your app.